# Launch two projects with VSCode Cmake that are in the same Cmake file

Tags: c++, cmake, vscode-extensions, cmakelists-options

I have two different projects in my CMakeLists.txt file.
I'm using a configuration like this in my `launch.json` file inside the `.vscode' folder:

```
 {
  "name": "Launch main project",
  "type": "cppdbg",
  "request": "launch",
  // Resolved by CMake Tools:
  "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
  "args": [],
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "environment": [
    {
      // add the directory where our target was built to the PATHs
      // it gets resolved by CMake Tools:
      "name": "PATH",
      "value": "${env:PATH}:${command:cmake.getLaunchTargetDirectory}"
    }
  ],
  "MIMode": "gdb",
  "setupCommands": [
    {
      "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
      "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
      "ignoreFailures": true
    }
  ]
},
```

trouble is, that the `vscode-cmake-tools` only recognizes the test project, and not my main project.

is there any way to tell vscode and the extention to run the main_project to run the other project?

---

this is my cmake file:

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0...3.5)
   project(main_project  VERSION 0.1.0)
   set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
   set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
   include(CPack)

   add_subdirectory( tests )  # this is the test project 
   add_executable(main_project main.cpp)
   target_include_directories(main_project  PRIVATE ${YOUR_DIRECTORY})
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a way to do it.
The "solution" I found was just to launch each one separately, and run a build task before each of them.

```
 // launch.json
 { "configurations": [
    {
     ...
     "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\build\\tests\\test_runner.exe",
     ...
     "preLaunchTask": "CMake: build"
     }
    ]
 }
```

And in the tasks.json:

```
{  
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cmake",
      "label": "CMake: build",
      "command": "build",
      "targets": ["main_project", "test_runner"],
      "group": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "detail": "CMake  build task"
    }
  ]
}
```